# I want to add strokes to a view

Tags: android

I'm trying to add strokes to a view using drawable.
But I want add it only in side parts(left and right), not in whole parts.
Is there any good way to add stroke in side parts?

Below is my drawable xml code. (leanear_border_gray.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#778899"/>

</shape>
```

and below is my target view xml code.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_border_gray"
        android:layout_weight="1">
       ....
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use vectors. fast and efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `shape` into `layer-list` `drawable` with rectangular shape, add stroke and using top and bottom margins with negative values "hide" top and bottom lines, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-4dp" android:bottom="-4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#778899"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `layer-list` `drawable` suggested by @iDemigod

Your Layout should be like this:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_left_right"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** If you are giving `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and  `android:layout_weight="1"` then you must have to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` and vice versa for `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

**File:** border_left_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="-4dp" android:bottom="-4dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#07060b"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Your comment helped me! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome Buddy @JungJaehoon